# Different <blockquote> for Quran, Hadith and others

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Apart from other StackExchange projects, Islam, Christianity, Judaism and other religious Q&A sites, especially the site of Islam, may contain 3 different types of `<blockquote>`s.

- `<blockquote_q>`Quranic Verses`</blockquote_q>`
- `<blockquote_h>`Hadith Verses`</blockquote_h>`
- `<blockquote>`All other quotes`</blockquote>`

**Reason:** In Islam, Quranic verses are highly acceptable with any Q or A. Hadithic verses are in this list, the second. And other verses or quotes are then in the rest. A Q or A cited with Quranic verses or Hadith verses will get more acceptance in general, so we can do CSS for them differently.

This is nothing but to do CSS for different types of verses differently.

#### For CSS suggestion

- **Quranic verses**
  with a soothing color background and some Arabic ornamental design at the edge or one side.
- **Hadith verses**
  with a soothing color background, different from Quranic verses, and some Arabic ornamental design at the edge or one side.
- **General Quotes**
  it can stay as it presently is.

<sub>**P.S.:** The same feature request can be implemented in the StackExchange site for Christianity, Judaism and all other sites required such kind of authentic text for the clarification or authenticity of the information.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting idea. However, we have no plans to support such a feature. For one thing, Islam.SE is still a beta site.  Upon graduation, the site will be given a beautiful new design to replace the fairly plain design that all beta sites use.  One of our [designers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/24481/senior-product-designer-stack-exchange) will work with the community to create a site that befits the topic.  (Take a look around at our [site list](http://stackexchange.com/sites#users) to get an idea of what to look forward to.)

Unfortunately, it's unlikely that the site will support two extra blockquote styles even after graduation.  We are [very reluctant](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/934/25092) to implement any further [Markdown](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) syntax that isn't standard.  Implementing an extension to HTML is pretty much out of the question.

As I said, I'm sympathetic to the concept, but we must decline it at this time.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195406/re-using-the-pre-formatted-text-button-on-sites-other-than-stack-overflow might be a (partial) solution, which doesn't require changes to markdown (only to the rendering).